# XSL for-each iteration

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have two for-each statements iterating and I want the output to be in vertical rather than horizontal format within the table.

Currently it outputs:

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

I want it to output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Can someone help please? Here is the XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:key name="names" match="Niche" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="niche" match="row" use="Niche"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <table border="1">

                <xsl:for-each select="//Niche[generate-id() = generate-id(key('names',.)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>

                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <td><tr></tr></td>

                <xsl:for-each select="//row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('niche', Niche)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="Niche"/>

                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('niche', Niche))"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </table>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl" ?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Niche>a</Niche>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Niche>b</Niche>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Niche>b</Niche>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Niche>c</Niche>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Niche>c</Niche>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Niche>c</Niche>
    </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the XML you're starting from, it's hard to decode what the stylesheet is doing without seeing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all you need to do is this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:key name="niche" match="Niche" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">

      <xsl:for-each select="//Niche[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('niche', .)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('niche', .))"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </table>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But please provide an example input XML so that we can verify.

On the sample input, this produces:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To instead sort from highest to lowest occurrence count, you could replace this line:

```
<xsl:sort select="."/>
```

with this:

```
<xsl:sort select="count(key('niche', .))" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
```

Comment: How would I go about sorting by the highest number? 

e.g.

c 3
b 2
a 1

Comment: Updated my answer.  Please see the comment at the end.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, seemed to output the left column in order? e.g. a 1 b 2 c 3

Comment: I didn't modify the original full XSLT.  Please see my comment at the end of the answer pointing out one line to replace with another.

Comment: Did that. I replaced <xsl:sort select="."/> with <xsl:sort select="count(key('niche', .))" order="descending"/> ... does not work .

Comment: It definitely works when I try it.  I get this output: `<table border="1"><tr><td>c</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>b</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>a</td><td>1</td></tr></table>` Same result when I try it on XSLFiddle.net.

Comment: arg... doesn't work with my actual XML file... cant post it because it's sensitive info

Comment: Could you post a small portion of it with the sensitive values replaced with sample values?  Is it at least the same structure as your sample, or is that different as well?

Comment: it seems to be ordering by the first number of a really large list. e.g. a 94 b 9 c 82 d 77 e 75 g 75 e 74

Comment: That wasn't a typo either... what I really mean, is the first number of the right hand column. e.g. 99, 9, 81, 71, 63, 6, 61 ...

Comment: I see. Sounds like the issue is that it's doing alphabetic sort rather than numeric. Could you add `data-type="number"` to the `<xsl:sort>` element? I thought the XSLT would have sorted based on the datatype of the formula result, but it looks like the default is "text".

Comment: awesome mate... you are a legend! :)